# How to Restrict the Circular Span of a Radial Fading Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, circles, tikzlibrary, tikz-fadings

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
% Code can be compiled with Pdflatex or Xelatex
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\definecolor{darkamber}{RGB}{213,54,0}
\definecolor{sunriseyellow}{RGB}{255,219,0}
\definecolor{topaz}{RGB}{255,200,124}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzset{
  star/.style={darkamber, fill=white, path fading=fade out}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
  \draw[black, shading=mradial, inner color=topaz, 
  middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow, outer color=darkamber]
  (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

which produces the circular radial effect

[image]

QUESTION: Instead of having the radial fading encompass an entire circle, I would like to display that portion of the radial circle ranging from -60 degrees to 240 degrees (i.e., I would like to remove the radial effect of the above image that covers 240-300 degrees from the solid darkamber background). How may I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Like this? `\draw[black, shading=mradial, inner color=topaz, 
  middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow, outer color=darkamber] (-60:2cm) arc (-60:240:2cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle;`

Comment: @Sigur Not exactly. When I replace my `\draw[black, shading ...;`  command with yours, I get the portion of the circular fading removed that I want, but so is the square darkamber solid background also removed, which I don't want to happen. Basically, I want to remove the angular portion of the fading which you did---but replace it with a solid darkamber "pie piece"  and keep everything else the same.

Comment: Why don't you just draw and fill this solid portion you want after the shading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to my above comment, here's the simplest solution that came to my mind. Just draw the pie piece above the shading.

[image: shading but not all]

```
\documentclass{book}
% Code can be compiled with Pdflatex or Xelatex
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\definecolor{darkamber}{RGB}{213,54,0}
\definecolor{sunriseyellow}{RGB}{255,219,0}
\definecolor{topaz}{RGB}{255,200,124}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzset{
  star/.style={darkamber, fill=white, path fading=fade out}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
  \draw[black, shading=mradial, inner color=topaz, 
  middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow, outer color=darkamber]
  (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
  \fill[darkamber] (240:4cm) arc (240:300:4cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle; % <---- The pie piece
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought perhaps there might be a way to restrict the "radial sweep" directly; but this gets the job done.

Comment: There is a way to restrict, but you need to fill the background before. In any case, you'll have to do it with two commands.