# Followup to Restricting the Circular Span of a Radial Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikzlibrary, degrees, tikz-fadings

This post is an extension of the post [How to Restrict the Circular Span of a Radial Fading Tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648379/how-to-restrict-the-circular-span-of-a-radial-fading-tikzpicture/648454?noredirect=1#comment1616286_648454)

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
% Code can be compiled with Pdflatex or Xelatex
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\definecolor{darkamber}{RGB}{213,54,0}
\definecolor{sunriseyellow}{RGB}{255,219,0}
\definecolor{topaz}{RGB}{255,200,124}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzset{
  star/.style={darkamber, fill=white, path fading=fade out}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
  \draw[darkamber, shading=mradial, inner color=topaz, 
  middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow, outer color=darkamber]
  (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{25pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
  \draw[darkamber, shading=mradial, inner color=topaz, 
  middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow, outer color=darkamber]
  (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
  \fill[darkamber] (180:4cm) arc (180:360:4cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle; % <---- The pie piece
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

which produces the two images:

[image]

I would like to be able to produce the second image in a more expedient manner; e.g., by specifying that the full-circle "radial glow" of the first image should only sweep out 0 degrees  to 180 degrees instead of the apparent default 0 degrees to 360 degrees.

The desired second image is obtained by superimposing a darkamber rectangle on the bottom half of the first image.

QUESTION: Is it possible, and if so, how may I modify the code which produces the first image so that it may be specified to produce the glow from (in this case) from 0 degrees to 180 degrees; and more generally, from, say, *a* degrees to *b* degrees without having to superimpose a second solid image atop the first to achieve the desired effect? Thank you.

NOTE: In [How to Restrict the Circular Span of a Radial Fading Tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648379/how-to-restrict-the-circular-span-of-a-radial-fading-tikzpicture/648454?noredirect=1#comment1616286_648454), user SebGlav says, ``There is a way to restrict, but you need to fill the background before. In any case, you'll have to do it with two commands.''

Comment: I still don't see the point in your question. You fill a square with your background colour, then fill a shape of your own with the shading and it produces what you want. If you want to restrict the shading to a specific shape, then you will *not* have a coloured background underneath it, unless you filled it before. Maybe could you elaborate about *why* you *need* to do these two commands in one, to enlighten us.

Comment: @SebGlav I tried to in the posting; perhaps I  was not clear enough. Let me try it this way by asking you this---If I wanted to create a radial glow for the portion of the circle, say, 75 le theta le 95 (degrees) , would it not be more expedient, if it were possible, to specify that along the lines I just did, as opposed to trying to figure out how to create the necessary polygon in order to superimpose it on the first image? I do not know if what I am looking for is possible, or feasible from your admonition. In any case, I thought I would ask. Thank you again for your previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a border for the full cutout rectangle, I'd go with clipping.

---

It won't be a problem to find the point on a square/rectangle in a direction from the origin, PGF ships with `\pgfpointborderrectangle` (this is used by the `rectangle` shape for the border anchors, but you will need to figure out which sides of the square/rectangle you need to hit and they are twenty options.

I'm too lazy to figure out the math and let you give these sides.
So for the angles `0` and `180` the partial rectangle would start at the `r`ight side and end at the `l`eft side, thus you specify

```
partial rectangle from = 0 to 180 sized 3 by 3 from r to l
```

The bottom part of that rectangle is then

```
partial rectangle from=180 to 360 sized 3 by 3 from l to r
```

And the bottom triangle part is

```
partial rectangle from=-60 to 240 sized 3 by 3 from b to b'
```

Notice the `'`: This means that we need to hit all four corners.
Without the `'` it would not hit any corner.

---

At the start it moves the path to the corners so that the fading is calculated across the whole rectangle and not only the partial one. (Comment it out to see what that means.)
I haven't found a way to exclude this points from the bounding box, though that shouldn't be a problem since you want to color in the remainder anyway.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={density=100}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\definecolor{darkamber}{RGB}{213,54,0}
\definecolor{sunriseyellow}{RGB}{255,219,0}
\definecolor{topaz}{RGB}{255,200,124}
\newcommand*\clipRectangle[3]{
  \pgfinterruptboundingbox\clip (0,0) -- ({#1}:{sqrt 2*max(#3)})
    arc[start angle={#1}, end angle={#2}, radius={sqrt 2*max(#3)}]
    -- cycle;\endpgfinterruptboundingbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\tikzScanOnePoint[1]{\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#1)}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  prf/.style 2 args={/utils/temp/.style={prf/##1=#2},/utils/temp/.list={#1}},
  prf/rr'/.style={prf={rt,tl,lb,br}{#1}},prf/tt'/.style={prf={tl,lb,br,rt}{#1}},
  prf/ll'/.style={prf={lb,br,rt,tl}{#1}},prf/bb'/.style={prf={br,rt,tl,lb}{#1}},
  prf/rt/.code 2 args=\pgfpathlineto{\tikzScanOnePoint{{#1},{#2}}},
  prf/tl/.code 2 args=\pgfpathlineto{\tikzScanOnePoint{{-(#1)},{#2}}},
  prf/lb/.code 2 args=\pgfpathlineto{\tikzScanOnePoint{{-(#1)},{-(#2)}}},
  prf/br/.code 2 args=\pgfpathlineto{\tikzScanOnePoint{{#1},{-(#2)}}},
  prf/rl/.style={prf/rt=#1,prf/tl=#1}, prf/tb/.style={prf/tl=#1,prf/lb=#1},
  prf/lr/.style={prf/lb=#1,prf/br=#1}, prf/bt/.style={prf/br=#1,prf/rt=#1},
  prf/rb/.style={prf/rl=#1,prf/lb=#1}, prf/tr/.style={prf/tb=#1,prf/br=#1},
  prf/lt/.style={prf/lr=#1,prf/rt=#1}, prf/bl/.style={prf/bt=#1,prf/tl=#1},
  partial rectangle from/.style args={#1 to #2 sized #3 by #4 from #5 to #6}{
    partial rectangle={#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5#6}},
  partial rectangle/.code n args={5}{% #1 = start angle
                                     % #2 = end angle
                                     % #3 = width radius
                                     % #4 = height radius
                                     % #5 = sides rtlb
%    \pgfinterruptboundingbox % doesn't work
      \pgfpathmoveto{\tikzScanOnePoint{{#3},{#4}}}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\tikzScanOnePoint{{-(#3)},{-(#4)}}}%
%    \endpgfinterruptboundingbox
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointborderrectangle{\pgfpointpolar{#1}{1pt}}
                  {\tikzScanOnePoint{{#3},{#4}}}}%
    \tikzset{prf/#5/.try={#3}{#4}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointborderrectangle{\pgfpointpolar{#2}{1pt}}
                  {\tikzScanOnePoint{{#3},{#4}}}}%
    \pgfpathclose
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\scoped
  \clipRectangle{-60}{240}{3}
  \path[
    shading=mradial,
    inner color=topaz, 
    middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow,
    outer color=darkamber,
  ] (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
\scoped
  \clipRectangle{240}{300}{3}
  \path[
    shading=mradial,
    inner color=darkamber,
    middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow,
    outer color=topaz,
  ] (-3, -3) rectangle (3, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz[ultra thick]
\draw[
  black,
  shading=mradial,
  inner color=topaz, 
  middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow,
  outer color=darkamber,
  partial rectangle from=-60 to 240 sized 3 by 3 from b to b'];

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\draw[
  black,
  shading=mradial,
  inner color=topaz, 
  middle color=darkamber!60!sunriseyellow,
  outer color=darkamber,
  partial rectangle from = 0 to 180 sized 3 by 3 from r to l];
\path[fill=darkamber, draw=black,
  partial rectangle from=180 to 360 sized 3 by 3 from l to r];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image][image]